# Close a mesh generating quads automatically

Tags: modeling, mesh, faces, topology

File link: [.Blend file](https://pasteall.org/blend/17b487d8f33746cfb0e55429c19a9e59)

I kept a clean topology, all quads while modeling, nonetheless, when the time to close the mesh arrives, I have this.

[image]

Is there a way to fill that face with quads without having to do it manually?
I tried Face>Grill Fill, and Face>Fill, then triangulate, then triangles to quads, it doesn't work.

I always get something like this.

[image]

I guess the only option is to do it manually. But worth asking since doing it manually will be time consuming and it's a situation I face often.

It's part of a droid leg.

Thanks!

Comment: Please share your file: https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: True, sorry. It's done, thanks

Comment: Try to use "simple blending" option in the grid fill operator panel (with a span or 2).

Comment: don't you want to simply extrude inwards and close with F? Do you absolutely need quads?

Comment: Closing with F causes crests with the subdivision surface modifier, that can be minimized with an edge loop.

I don't absolutely need quads. I just want to know if there is a better way to solve this.

Comment: FWIW I close with F and then inset the new face.  That creates a loop you can use for a control loop.  Repeating the inset a few times will give you a lot of control, at the expense of a lot of vertices.